# Is It possible to Disable JS for my website on my server

Tags: javascript, android, web-hosting

I'm trying to connect my android app to a PHP script on a free server. But as my android app is Trying to get to the page I'm getting an HTML that says that JS is turned off, Switch it on to view the page.
Can I Disable the JS requirement on my server?

Comment: Are you using a WebView? JS has to be manually enabled then.

Comment: JavaScript has nothing to do with turning on and off at the server level.... That is a browser/device level setting.

Comment: @epascarello Exactly when I turn off the JS on my browser I Get the same message, but there are many websites that run with JS off, is there something that I can do to make it allow devices with Javascript disabled to access the page.

Comment: @JonasWilms Im not using a web view, Im just sending a post request to a php script on my server, and getting the echoed text as a `toast`

Comment: The application probably has a <noscript> tag or something. Impossible to tell without looking at the site. It is up to the site to handle JavaScript disabled. There is no simple on off switch. It has to be coded.

Comment: @epascarello I thought that too, but I have only 2 files on my server, and both contain only `php` code.and im directly accessing one of the files.

Comment: What happens when you send the same post request from a desktop browser or via postman? Also, who is the provider of your server?

Comment: when I send the same request from my browser (with JS enabled), I get the the text that was supposed to be echoed, but when I disable JS I get the same error `This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support`. and im using infinityfree.net

Comment: Again something is making the check. Impossible to know without seeing it. My guess is the web host is injecting something into the page for ads and that is what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is their security (On premium hosting, this security system is not present)

https://infinityfree.net/support/javascript-error-using-api-or-mobile-android-app/